# Meteor.js - node server security?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, server

So, today I have researched the security of node.js servers. As many of you may know they can give you a headache when it comes to security. So I have two questions:

1. The only dependency a build meteor-server/package has is node. Does it have the same issues? I know node has it's own security features but are they enogh here?
2. How can I make a server more secure? Is it the same as with node.js servers? And does somebody of you have a good resource on making node "safer"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://guide.meteor.com/security.html

Comment: What Hackerman said. Meteor has it's own host of security concerns and mitigations. Anytime you use any framework or code base, there are always security implications unique to them.

Comment: So concerns about nodes security issues are overreacted, so that I should only have concerns about my clients?

Comment: Way too broad a question...

Comment: Dito, please be more specific. Security concerns begin already by developing a piece of code that runs on a server... no matter what ws or language.

Comment: Should you be concerned about security? Yes.